How to typeset the a combination of math and a plot
I want to to typeset the following equation as in the picture in LaTeX, but I have no idea how to do it. I know how to typeset the l.h.s. but I have no idea for the r.h.s.
Could you please help me with that? Many thanks in advance.


you can use array enviroment,
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, array}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{document}
\[
  |I,T,T_3 = T \rangle = \begin{array}{|w{c}{1.8cm}|w{c}{1.8cm}|}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{p} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{n}  \\
    \hline
        & \bullet \\\hline
        & \bullet \\\hline
        & \bullet \\\hline
        & \bullet \\\hline
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}



Why those complications? Isn't w{c}{1.8cm} simpler than p{1.8cm}<{\centering}? And why \left and \right? There is no m option to array. By the way, compiling your code doesn't produce the same image.

w{c}{1.8cm} does it need support from a certain package?

It has been featured in array for a few years. By the way, it uses math mode if called in the array environment, so you don't need to use $.

Thanks, I've re-edited my comment.

There is no problem in adding array in an equation.
With the w{c}{2em} column type, you get fixed width (change the length to your liking). Omitting rules is done as usual in array or tabular.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
\lvert I,T,T_{3}=T\rangle =
\begin{array}{|w{c}{2em}|w{c}{2em}|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{p} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{n} \\
\hline
& \bullet \\
\hline
& \bullet \\
\hline
& \bullet \\
\hline
& \bullet \\
\hline
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}

I don't think you want to really have the headers of the table in sans serif upright as they probably denote math variables.


Not a hard one.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
  \lvert I, T, T_3=T>=\begin{NiceArray}{cc}[hvlines, first-row]
    p & n\\
    & \bullet\\
    & \bullet\\
    & \bullet\\
    & \bullet\\
  \end{NiceArray}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}


Edit
With \rangle and setting columns width:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
  \lvert I, T, T_3=T \rangle =\begin{NiceArray}{cc}[columns-width = 1cm, hvlines, first-row]
    p & n\\
    & \bullet\\
    & \bullet\\
    & \bullet\\
    & \bullet\\
  \end{NiceArray}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}



It's better to use \rangle instead of >

@MadyYuvi thanks, I've been too fast ;)
